# How stop multiple projects in vscode with the launch.json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, visual-studio-code, configuration-files

I have in my launch.JSON a configuration that allows me to start two different API projects at the same time (Web API One and Web API Two), both are components of the same project, everything works fine on start, but if I need to stop the APIs I need to stop each of them individually, theirs a way to create a config file to stop both projects at the same time?

Observation: I use only two projects in this code example, but in reality, I have six APIs and other projects like services and front-end projects.

Most C# projects, Windows Services and Web APIs, but I want to include JavaScript front-end projects in the future.

My launch.JSON:

```
// Components for start menu in vscode debug mode
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Web API",
            "configurations": 
            [
                "Web API One",
                "Web API Two"
            ]
        }
    ],

// Configuration of each project
    "configurations": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Web API One",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "buildWEBAPI",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/WEBAPI/PATH",
            "args": 
            [
                "--force"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/01.Application/WEBAPI",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "env": 
            {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Web API Two",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "buildWEBAPI",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/WEBAPI/PATH",
            "args": 
            [
                "--force"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/01.Application//WEBAPI/",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "env": 
            {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this question better suited for superuser website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question because I found a solution. Based on my search, this approach using .json config file is not possible, but an alternative is to click "shift + F5" on a call stack tab in vscode when the project is running and held until all projects has been stopped